# Windows7 home 64bit + Outlook 2010, multiple non-concurrent users

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

We have one windows computer shared by eight people. I have set up separate login accounts for each user. One account has administrative privileges, the others are standard users.

We installed Outlook 2010 with the intention that each user could access their own email separately, without seeing the mail of other users.

This has not worked as we intended. When the administrator logs in to each standard user account and starts the outlook mail setup, he is prompted for the administrative password, and then sets up the mail account. When accessing the outlook mail program after setup, each mail account shows as a separate tab in a communal inbox, rather than a separate mail box for each user.

How would we accomplish the desired separation of Outlook mail accounts?

Thanks for your advice
Jim T.

Comment: You need to setup the inboxes as the standard Windows Users, not as the administrator. I haven't done this before but I believe there are 2 separate parts to having Outlook on the accounts (1) Installation (2) Profile Setup. See if you can find the separation between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to set up separate profiles if you go to control panel > mail >profile area. This [outlook KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918) should help.